# PHPExcel - No content in my excel file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I try to export a list of timesheets in an Excel file but anything appear when I open my Excel file. Excel display this message :

"Désolé... Nous avons trouvé un problème dans le contenu de "test_export.xlsx", mais nous pouvons essayer de récupérer le maximum de contenu. Si la source de ce classeur est fiable, cliquez sur Oui."

If I click on yes, my spreadsheet is empty.

Here is my code in my TimesheetController :

```
public function exportAction()
{

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    $timesheetsArray = array();
    $timesheetsObject = array();

    if($request->isPost())
    {

        $data = $request->getPost();
        foreach($data['rows'] as $id)
        {
            $timesheetsObject[] = $em->getRepository($this->repositoryName)->find($id);
        }
        foreach($timesheetsObject as $object){
            $object->setIdFiche((string)$object->getIdFiche());
            $object->setEvaUser((string)$object->getEvaUser());
            $object->setId((string)$object->getId());
            $object->setProject((string)$object->getProject());
            $object->setUser((string)$object->getUser());
            $object->setEstimatedTime((string)$object->getEstimatedTime());
            $object->setTimeSpend((string)$object->getTimeSpend());
            $object->setStartDate($object->getStartDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $object->setEndDate($object->getEndDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $timesheetsArray[] = $object->getArrayCopy();
        }

    }

    $export = new Export\ExportExcel();
    $export->export($timesheetsArray);

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'export' => $export
    ));

}
```

And here is my ExportExcel class :

```
class ExportExcel {

public function __construct(){

}

function export($timesheets)
{
    /** Error reporting */
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    $workbook = new \PHPExcel();
    $workbook->createSheet();
    $workbook->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($timesheets, NULL, 'A2');

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test_export.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

    $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($workbook, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}

}
```

I work with PHP, ZendFramework and DoctrineORM.

Have you a solution for me ?

Thanks !

And sorry if my english is not good.

Comment: Could you translate the French text to English, please?!

Comment: If your framework is generating any output or headers via the call to `return new ViewModel(array(
        'export' => $export
    ));
` then you need to prevent it from doing so. Your `ExportExcel::export() is already generating its own headers and the only output that should be generated.... note that

Comment: Of course : Sorry... We found a problem in the content of "test_export.xlsx", but we can try to retrieve the maximum of content. If the origin is trusted click on Yes."

Comment: @MarkBaker There is a weird output. Here is an extract :
`PKRøFjÒc]x[Content_Types].xmlÅÍNÃ0ï<Eä+ÝöjÚ#T¢<±7UÇ¶¼îßÛ³IZ@H¨ZK¬Èù&ãMÆÓ]m³
D4ÞlÈ,§¼6nY°÷Ås~Ï2LÒii½íÙtr3^ì`Fb«R
B ª È}G;¥µLt"HµK£ÁàN(ï¸§ÆMÆ¯ÄFC61½È0bgE"7è®CN~,{ì
»`2kL\lþEÍ}YÚ«uMÞÚÜ6.â$ÓÞ^ÂAj¬Rmygz$Ï k²§¹wG°xïP&'eûV&ôú_è´nsa¤E¹¥Qê)}ëãêÃûÕµkoV^KãúÄóè`

Comment: That's not weird; it looks like the Excel2007 datastream.... have you ever tried opening an xlsx file in a text editor?

Comment: Like I said, you need to suppress any output or headers that your framework might be generating

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MarkBaker, but i can't suppress the generation of layout... You think that come from there ?

Comment: If you're using any of the main PHP frameworks, they should all provide some mechanism for disabling their own output and allowing controllers to use their own output/headers/etc

Comment: Okay, i'll seek ! I use ZendFramework ;) Thank you !

Comment: Depending on version of ZF, something like `$layout->disableLayout();`

Comment: I work with ZF2... I found a solution who like this but not working with AbstractActionController :/

Comment: @MarkBaker I succed to disable layout so there aren't any outputs or headers but there are always no content in my excel file and no error message.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bug found : actually, there was a double call of the function and between those two calls the isPost() was reset to 'false' so the condition wasn't true at the second call. That's why the Excel array was empty at the end.

Answer (score 0):

So I found where the second call was. But if I remove this, there are not save of my Excel file because my Export button don't go to the export view.

Have you a solution ?